# AWS S3 uploading directly and automatically making file public

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I'm uploading files via a htmlpage directly using CORS, it's all working fine. The problem is the files aren't public read, so I would like to make automatically public read.

Here's the policy I think should do it but doesn't work.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bucket policies do not apply to objects "owned" by others, even though they are within your bucket, so the only way to do this is to make public during the upload using a request header.

```
request.AddHeader("x-amz-acl", "public-read");
```